# Maths quiz random numbers and size, except ValueERROR

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
from random import randint

user_name = input("\nHello, please enter your name: ").title().strip()
print ("Alright",user_name,"Welcome to your maths quiz")
score=0
incorrect = 0 

for question_num in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        try:    
            size = ["bigger", "smaller"]
            rand = randint(0,100)
            rand2 = randint(0,100)
            size_question = randint(0, len(size) - 1)
            print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
            question_num += 1
            print ("Which number is", size[size_question], rand, "or", rand2)
            answer = int(input ("What is your answer: "))
            if size[size_question] == "bigger":
                if rand > rand2 and rand == answer:
                    print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1 
                elif rand2 > rand and rand2 == answer:
                    print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
            elif size[size_question] == "smaller": 
                if rand < rand2 and rand == answer:
                    print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
                elif rand2 < rand and rand2 == answer:
                    print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1   

        except ValueError:
            print ("Incorrect")
            if score > 0:
                score -= 1
```

Comment: Why does the value error not work?

Comment: What do you mean 'not work'? What is your expected output and what are you getting? Where do you believe a `ValueError` exception is being raised?

Comment: when the answer is incorrect, incorrect is not printing!

Comment: How does the program know it is incorrect, at no point is a `ValueError` being raised. Exception blocks are only executed when that exception is raised. Looks like you just need conditional logic, not exception logic.

Comment: `ValueError` is only raised in your code if the user does not enter an integer, it is not raised if the answer is wrong. If the answer is wrong, nothing happens. The `while True` loop also has nothing to break it, meaning this code will run forever. As @AChampion says, you need to use conditional logic, the `except` clause is not even necessary here, you can test for an integer with `isdigit()`

Comment: I suggest that you use smaller `try` blocks , and use the generic `Except` if you are not sure about the exception type

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

user_name = input("\nHello, please enter your name: ").title().strip()
print ("Welcome",user_name,"to the maths quiz")
score=0
incorrect = 0 
question_num = 1

while question_num <= 3:
    try:    
        size = ["bigger", "smaller"]
        rand = randint(0,100)
        rand2 = randint(0,100)
        size_question = randint(0, len(size) - 1)
        print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
        question_num += 1
        print ("Which number is", size[size_question], rand, "or", rand2)
        answer = int(input ("What is your answer: "))
        if size[size_question] == "bigger":
            if rand > rand2 and rand == answer:
                print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                score += 1 
            elif rand2 > rand and rand2 == answer:
                print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                score += 1
            elif rand2 != answer:
                print ("Incorrect")
                if score > 0:
                    score -= 1  
            elif rand != answer:
                print ("Incorrect")
                if score > 0:
                    score -= 1             
        elif size[size_question] == "smaller": 
            if rand < rand2 and rand == answer:
                print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                score += 1
            elif rand2 < rand and rand2 == answer:
                print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                score += 1                       
            elif rand2 != answer:
                print ("Incorrect")
                if score > 0:
                    score -= 1                
            elif rand != answer:
                print ("Incorrect")
                if score > 0:
                    score -= 1                    

    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter numbers only")
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try like this. You are not capturing the error when someone types in a value other than the ones that you are looking for.

```
from random import randint

user_name = input("\nHello, please enter your name: ").title().strip()
print ("Alright", user_name, "Welcome to your maths quiz")
score = 0
incorrect = 0

for question_num in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        try:
            size = ["bigger", "smaller"]
            rand = randint(0, 100)
            rand2 = randint(0, 100)
            size_question = randint(0, len(size) - 1)
            print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
            question_num += 1
            print ("Which number is", size[size_question], rand, "or", rand2)
            answer = int(input("What is your answer: "))
            if size[size_question] == "bigger":
                if answer not in [rand, rand2]:
                    raise ValueError("Incorrect value is supplied")

                if rand > rand2 and rand == answer:
                    print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
                elif rand2 > rand and rand2 == answer:
                    print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
            elif size[size_question] == "smaller":
                if answer not in [rand, rand2]:
                    raise ValueError("Incorrect value is supplied")

                if rand < rand2 and rand == answer:
                    print("correct", rand, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
                elif rand2 < rand and rand2 == answer:
                    print("correct", rand2, "is", size[size_question])
                    score += 1
        except ValueError:
            print ("Incorrect")
            if score > 0:
                score -= 1
```

I have added a `raise Exception` to capture the error condition. However you can choose different ways to capture your message. This actually puts an end to the program. But if you want to continue you can use print it out.

Also you should look in to the documentation of python to know when exactly you should use `try and except`. Hope this helps.